# How to troubleshoot heroku rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake-task

I have rake tasks that work fine in localhost.  When i run rake task:task_name it executes fine.  In heroku, when i run heroku run rake task:task_name it does not execute.  Logs doesn't seem to contain information on this.  Is there somewhere I can go to see why this isn't working?

I also have this set up in my scheduler but that's not working either.  It completes fine but doesn't actually seem to do what it should (send an email out).

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your rake task writes to the log, it won't generate any logs. You should add in some logging statements that give you some waypoints that you know you are hitting, so you can start to see where the task falls over. From there, you can drill in and add more logging statements